# Typescript decorator order; get ClassDecorator information in MethodDecorator

Tags: typescript

Since the [decorator evaluation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#decorator-evaluation) says that `ClassDecorator`s come last, how to get information in a `MethodDecorator` which comes from the `ClassDecorator`?

An example would be a `@Controller(prefix: string)` decorator which prefixes all routes within this controller. Something like this:

```
const Controller = (prefix: string) : ClassDecorator => {
  return target => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('prefix', prefix, target);
  };
};

const Get = (path: string) : MethodDecorator => {
  return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    // add this route to the router, prefixed with the `prefix` metadata from the controller
  };
};

@Controller('/foo')
class Foo {
  @Get('/bar')
  bar() {
  }
}
```

Using this code the `prefix` metadata from `target` in `Get` is `undefined`.

Comment: Have `Get` define metadata for each route and have `Controller` add them to the router the end?

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you should define metadata for each call to `Get` where you store what you need (in general, you can store the property key and descriptor if you need them; otherwise, store only what you actually need).  Then, in the call to `Controller`, read in all that metadata and do what you want with it.   For example:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

// stuff to store with each call to Get
interface GetMethodInfo {
  propertyKey: string | symbol;
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>
}

const Get = (path: string) : MethodDecorator => {
  return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    if (!Reflect.hasMetadata('get-methods',target)) {
      // store an array if it's not there already
      Reflect.defineMetadata('get-methods', [], target);
    } 
    const getMethods: Array<GetMethodInfo> = Reflect.getMetadata('get-methods', target);
    // push the new information into that array
    getMethods.push({propertyKey: propertyKey, descriptor: descriptor})    
  };
};

const Controller = (prefix: string) : ClassDecorator => {
  return target => {
    // read in the array from the metadata (may be undefined if no calls to Get)
    const getMethods: Array<GetMethodInfo> = Reflect.getMetadata('get-methods', target) || []; 
    getMethods.forEach(getMethodInfo => {
      // add this route to the router, prefixed with the `prefix` metadata from the controller
    })
  };
};


@Controller('/foo')
class Foo {
  @Get('/bar')
  bar() {
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.